# Synonyms of 'bitter-sweet'

Tags: synonyms

Are there any synonyms for *bitter-sweet*? I've tried having a look on online thesauri, but haven't had much luck in finding anything suitable.

**The context I wish to use this in:**
I have described something (the proliferation of data) in text as having both positive and negative attributes, and would like to state that something else, similarly, possesses this 'bitter-sweet' characteristic.

I don't want to use 'bitter-sweet', however, because it doesn't sound serious or formal enough in the context I am using it in, if that makes sense. Is there another word that describes something as having both beneficial *and* disadvantageous features?

Comment: In a way, it’s ambivalent (or perhaps rather, your attitude towards it is). Or it’s a **double-edged sword** (though that does feel a bit odd in your particular situation).

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think either of these express precisely what I have in mind, but thanks for the suggestions :) I just found this awesome word, though: **agathokakological** (composed of both good and evil)

Comment: Try "mixed blessing" or "both a blessing and a curse." I cannot share your enthusiasm for *agathokakological:* yes, it combines Greek for *good* and *bad,* but the addition of the *-logical* part makes it an adjective for characterizing something as involved with *discourse about* good and bad (often especially *academic* or *scientific* discourse).

Comment: @BrianDonovan I see what you mean... :( Think I'll go for "both a blessing and a curse" in that case.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you use _agathokakological_, be prepared that your readers are probably not going to have a clue what you’re talking about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, I considered that. Still, it's definitely my word of the day, even if I can't use it (:

Comment: Also consider “The proliferation of data is lolsobby, in that ...” (on web, *lolsob* is explained via “Because if you can't laugh, you've got to cry”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going for a complex adjectival phrase, or for a rare allusion, I would suggest using a simple declarative approach and rhetoric. This will help keep the writing vigorous.

**The proliferation of data within text is not without problems**.

The use of litotes -- "... not without ..." -- both rhetorically suggests and then refutes the assertion that the trend is unproblematic, but does so compactly.